# SQL Mi procedimiento para detectar UPDATE de manera dinamica corre lento con tablas grandes

Tags: sql, servidor

acabo de terminar un trigger para detectar si realizaron una actualizcion a un registro de una tabla, pero mi tabla contiene mas de 30 campos y tarda alrededor de 8 segundos en realizar la actualizacion, siendo que sin el trigger tarda a lo mucho segundo y medio. 
Tal vez para mi no sea mucho pero para el cliente final si sera demasiado, mas si actualizar es una actividad repetitiva durante el desempeno de su actividad.
Alguien tiene alguna idea de como mejorar el rendimiento de mi trigger. 
Gracias.

```
/****************************************************************************/

create TRIGGER bit_MNT36_update
ON MNT36
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        -- ===============================================================================================================================
        -- [0.0].- Declaración e inicialización de variables
        -- ===============================================================================================================================
        DECLARE
            @campo_pk   VARCHAR(100),
            @campo_pk2  VARCHAR(100),
            @campo_pk3  VARCHAR(100),
            @fecha      DATE,
            @hora       VARCHAR(30),
            @cont       INT,
            @top        INT,
            @tabla      VARCHAR(100),
            @campo      VARCHAR(100),
            @total_pk   NVARCHAR(100)
    SET @campo_pk   = ''
    SET @campo_pk2  = ''
    SET @campo_pk3  = ''
    SET @fecha      = NULL
    SET @hora       = ''
    SET @tabla      = ''
    SET @campo      = ''
    SET @cont       = 0
    SET @top        = 0
    SET @total_pk   = 0
    -- ===============================================================================================================================
    -- Obtener los campos que conforman la llave primaria
    -- ===============================================================================================================================
    IF OBJECT_ID (N'bit13', N'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE bit13

    CREATE TABLE bit13
    (
        ID          INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
        campo_pk    VARCHAR(100)
    )

    INSERT INTO bit13
    SELECT
        column_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KU ON TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    AND
        TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KU.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    AND 
        KU.table_name='mnt36'

    SET @total_pk = (select count(*) from bit13)

    IF not exists(SELECT campo_pk FROM BIT13 WHERE ID = 1) 
        BEGIN
            SET @campo_pk = 'NULL'
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @campo_pk   = (SELECT campo_pk  FROM bit13 WHERE ID = 1)
    END
    IF not exists(SELECT campo_pk FROM BIT13 WHERE ID = 2)
        BEGIN
            SET @campo_pk2 = 'NULL'
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @campo_pk2  = (SELECT campo_pk  FROM bit13 WHERE ID = 2)
        END
    IF not exists(SELECT campo_pk FROM BIT13 WHERE ID = 3) 
        BEGIN
            SET @campo_pk3 = 'NULL'
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @campo_pk3  = (SELECT campo_pk  FROM bit13 WHERE ID = 3)
        END

    -- ===============================================================================================================================
    --[1.1].- Almacenar en la tabla temporal los campos a recorrer
    -- ===============================================================================================================================
    -- [1.1.1].- Crear tabla temporal para almancenar la relación Tabla-Campos
    IF OBJECT_ID (N'bit11', N'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE [bit11]

    CREATE TABLE [bit11]
    (
        ID      INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
        Tabla   VARCHAR(100),
        Campo   VARCHAR(100)
    )
    -- [1.1.2].- Limpiar la tabla temporal 
    TRUNCATE TABLE [bit11]

    -- [1.1.3].- Almacenar el listado de campos en la tabla temporal
    INSERT INTO [bit11]
    SELECT
        obj.name        AS [Tabla],
        col.name        AS [Campo]--,
        --tipoDato.name AS [TipoDato]
    FROM sysObjects obj
    INNER JOIN sysColumns col       ON obj.id = col.id
    INNER JOIN sys.types tipoDato   ON col.xtype = tipoDato.system_type_id
    WHERE
        obj.name = 'MNT36' 
    AND
        obj.xType = 'U'
    ORDER BY
        col.colorder
    -- ===============================================================================================================================
    --[1.2].- Loop para revisar si existio una modificación
    -- ===============================================================================================================================
    -- [1.2.0].- Inicializar variables
    SET @cont = 1
    SET @top = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [bit11])

    SET @fecha  = CONVERT(DATE ,GETDATE())
    SET @hora   = LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE(), 100), 7))

    WHILE(@cont <= @top) -- LOOP - A
    BEGIN
        -- [1.2.1].- Obtener campo x campo del listado
        SELECT
            @tabla = Tabla,
            @campo = Campo
        FROM [bit11]
        WHERE 
            ID = @cont

        -- [1.2.2].- Eliminar tablas temporales en caso de existir  
        IF OBJECT_ID (N'DELETED_MNT36', N'U') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE [DELETED_MNT36]

        IF OBJECT_ID (N'INSERTED_MNT36', N'U') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE [INSERTED_MNT36]

        -- [1.2.3].- Crear tablas temporales de las tablas que contienen
                --  los datos antes y despues de ser actualizados
        SELECT * INTO [DELETED_MNT36] FROM DELETED
        SELECT * INTO [INSERTED_MNT36] FROM INSERTED

        -- [1.2.4].- Registrar en bitacora los cambios de la tabla
        IF (@total_pk = 1)
            EXEC('
                DECLARE 
                    @valor_pk   VARCHAR(100),
                    @valor_ant  VARCHAR(3000),
                    @valor_new  VARCHAR(3000)

                            IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bit13 WHERE ID = 1) > 0
                                SELECT @valor_pk = '+@campo_pk+' FROM DELETED_MNT36

                                IF EXISTS(SELECT *
                                FROM INSERTED_MNT36 I
                                INNER JOIN DELETED_MNT36 D ON I.'+@campo_pk+' = D.'+@campo_pk+'
                                AND I.'+@campo+' <> D.'+ @campo +'
                                )
                                BEGIN
                                    SELECT 
                                        @valor_pk   = '+@campo_pk+',
                                        @valor_ant  = '+@campo+'
                                    FROM DELETED_MNT36

                                    SELECT @valor_new = '+@campo+' FROM INSERTED_MNT36

                                    INSERT INTO [bit12](tipo,
                                                        tabla,
                                                        campo_pk,
                                                        valor_pk,
                                                        campo,
                                                        valor_anterior,
                                                        valor_nuevo,
                                                        fecha,
                                                        hora)
                                    SELECT      ''U'',              
                                                '''+@tabla+''',     
                                                '''+@campo_pk+''',  
                                                @valor_pk,                  
                                                '''+@campo+''',     
                                                @valor_ant,         
                                                @valor_new,         
                                                '''+@fecha+''',     
                                                '''+@hora+'''       
                                END
            ')
        IF (@total_pk = 2)
            EXEC('
                DECLARE 
                    @valor_pk   VARCHAR(100),
                    @valor_pk2  VARCHAR(100),
                    @valor_ant  VARCHAR(3000),
                    @valor_new  VARCHAR(3000)

                    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bit13 WHERE ID = 1) > 0
                        SELECT @valor_pk = '+@campo_pk+' FROM DELETED_MNT36
                    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bit13 WHERE ID = 2) > 0
                        SELECT @valor_pk2 = '+@campo_pk2+' FROM DELETED_MNT36

                            IF EXISTS(SELECT *
                            FROM INSERTED_MNT36 I
                            INNER JOIN DELETED_MNT36 D ON I.'+@campo_pk+' = D.'+@campo_pk+'
                            AND I.'+@campo_pk2+' = D.'+@campo_pk2+'
                            AND I.'+@campo+' <> D.'+ @campo +'
                            )
                                BEGIN
                                    SELECT 
                                        @valor_pk   = '+@campo_pk+',
                                        @valor_ant  = '+@campo+'
                                    FROM DELETED_MNT36

                                    SELECT @valor_new = '+@campo+' FROM INSERTED_MNT36

                                    INSERT INTO [bit12](tipo,
                                                        tabla,
                                                        campo_pk,
                                                        valor_pk,
                                                        campo_pk2,
                                                        valor_pk2,
                                                        campo,
                                                        valor_anterior,
                                                        valor_nuevo,
                                                        fecha,
                                                        hora)
                                    SELECT      ''U'',              
                                                '''+@tabla+''',     
                                                '''+@campo_pk+''',  
                                                @valor_pk,
                                                '''+@campo_pk2+''',
                                                @valor_pk2,                     
                                                '''+@campo+''',     
                                                @valor_ant,         
                                                @valor_new,         
                                                '''+@fecha+''',     
                                                '''+@hora+'''       
                                END
            ')
            IF (@total_pk = 3)
            EXEC('
                DECLARE 
                    @valor_pk   VARCHAR(100),
                    @valor_pk2  VARCHAR(100),
                    @valor_pk3  VARCHAR(100),
                    @valor_ant  VARCHAR(3000),
                    @valor_new  VARCHAR(3000)

                    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bit13 WHERE ID = 1) > 0
                        SELECT @valor_pk = '+@campo_pk+' FROM DELETED_imp02
                    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bit13 WHERE ID = 2) > 0
                        SELECT @valor_pk2 = '+@campo_pk2+' FROM DELETED_imp02
                    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bit13 WHERE ID = 3) > 0
                        SELECT @valor_pk3 = '+@campo_pk3+' FROM DELETED_imp02

                            IF EXISTS(SELECT *
                            FROM INSERTED_imp02 I
                            INNER JOIN DELETED_imp02 D ON I.'+@campo_pk+' = D.'+@campo_pk+'
                            AND I.'+@campo+' <> D.'+ @campo+'
                            )
                                BEGIN
                                    SELECT 
                                        @valor_pk   = '+@campo_pk+',
                                        @valor_ant  = '+@campo+'
                                    FROM DELETED_imp02
                                    SELECT @valor_new = '+@campo+' FROM INSERTED_imp02
                                    INSERT INTO [bit12](tipo,
                                                        tabla,
                                                        campo_pk,
                                                        valor_pk,
                                                        campo_pk2,
                                                        valor_pk2,
                                                        campo_pk3,
                                                        valor_pk3,
                                                        campo,
                                                        valor_anterior,
                                                        valor_nuevo,
                                                        fecha,
                                                        hora)
                                    SELECT      ''U'',              
                                                '''+@tabla+''',     
                                                '''+@campo_pk+''',  
                                                @valor_pk,
                                                '''+@campo_pk2+''',
                                                @valor_pk2,
                                                '''+@campo_pk3+''',
                                                @valor_pk3,                         
                                                '''+@campo+''',     
                                                @valor_ant,         
                                                @valor_new,         
                                                '''+@fecha+''',     
                                                '''+@hora+'''       
                                END
            ')
        -- [1.2.5].- Incrementar el contador del Loop
        SET @cont = @cont + 1
    END -- LOOP - A

    -- ===============================================================================================================================
    --[1.3].- Eliminar tablas temporales
    -- ===============================================================================================================================
    IF OBJECT_ID (N'bit11', N'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE [bit11]

    IF OBJECT_ID (N'DELETED_MNT36', N'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE [DELETED_MNT36]

    IF OBJECT_ID (N'INSERTED_MNT36', N'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE [INSERTED_MNT36]

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Comment: wow....ese trigger está haciendo una enorme cantidad de cosas que me da la impresión que no son necesarias. Puedes explicar cuál es el objetivo del trigger?

Comment: El objetivo principal es detectar el valor anterior y el valor nuevo de un registro de una tabla, lo intento hacer de una manera dinamica ya que cuento con mas de 100 tablas en mi base de datos.

Comment: Pero no es necesario hacerlo dinámico. Tú tienes un trigger creado en esa tabla, por lo que el código dentro del trigger es cuando algún valor de esa tabla está siendo modificado/insertado